# Guitar Hero Live Controller Dongle Compatibility; Where to get dongle?

Tags: guitar-hero-live

I've been told that the guitar controllers for GH:Live are compatible with any platform, but the wireless dongles are platform specific.

I have one PS4 and one PS3 dongle and two guitar controllers.

When I plugged in the PS4 dongle to my PS3, that controller synced as player one, but wouldn't let me play - which is expected.

Is there any workaround for this so I can play multiplayer on a PS3, or is there someway I can procure only the PS3 dongle without getting another guitar controller along with it?

Comment: Asking where to get a dongle is a shopping recommendation.  The rest...might be acceptable, but you should remove that part.

Comment: Dongles aren't yet sold individually, which is why I asked. Thanks to the answer, I now know that I can talk to ATVI about replacement. I don't ever understand the hostility for a legitimate question on Stack Exchange sites...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, try ebay and amazon, but yours may be hard to find.  You could order a replacement part through Activision Support, per their [recommendation](https://community.guitarhero.com/message/415871708#415871708) to someone who lost theirs.

[Support Instructions from this site:](https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Download-Disc-Replacement-Form/?q=return&l=en_US&c=Game_Title%3AAll&fs=Search&pn=1)

Follow these steps to submit a standard warranty claim:

1. Select Warranty at the top of any page.
2. Select Hardware, and then select the appropriate Hardware category:
   All Other Hardware — Enter the name of the hardware item, select it from the available options, and then select Continue.
3. Confirm the item you selected, and then complete the Warranty form.

They added Guitar Hero Live Dongle (PlayStation 3) as a Hardware option since the support post referenced.  Typing Guitar Hero Live into the form will show the auto complete options for the Dongle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I sent a support claim and they mailed be a dongle free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

I lost my USB Dongle for Xbox 360 and contacted Activision Support. After 4 Days they sent me a new one for free!